# Calling Ads API reachestimate returns "Application does not have permission for this action"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Following the Ads API docs for reachestimate (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/reachestimate/), I received a "false" response when calling

**https://graph.facebook.com/act_0000000000000000/reachestimate?currency=EUR&targeting_spec={'countries':['US']}&access_token=*_*__**

(Note: act_0000000000000000 is my user Id and **_** is my access token - these tokens work correctly for other Ads API calls).

Using the Graph API Explorer tool, I receive the following response on this API call

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10
  }
}
```

However, when I call

**https://graph.facebook.com/1111111111111111/reachestimate?currency=EUR&targeting_spec={'countries':['US']}&access_token=*_*__**

where 1111111111111111 is an adgroup, I get a valid data structure.

Has anyone come across this elsewhere? Is there a "magic" setting somewhere that enables this capability on the user account (enabled for ads_management, offline_access)?

Any thoughts very welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: These are probably a stupid questions, but a) is your app definitely in the ads API whitelist? and b) - did you make a mistake when copy/pasting the method name? you have `reachestiamte`, not `reachestimate` (twice)

Comment: @Igy - typo was my mistake on posting this question - edited question, and verified that still same issue on API. Also, App is API whitelisted, and all other API calls work as per Facebook documentation. Unfortunately, the issue is still very real. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Is `act_0000000000000000 is my user Id` also a typo? That's supposed to be the ad account ID, not the user ID

Comment: @Igy - I think that might be it... makes me feel a little dumb, but I guess I've been staring at the obvious for too long. Thanks for the pointer - appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Igy - just confirmed that my issue was indeed the misuse of my UserID in account field - have since migrated these queries to use the designated account ID and works as expected.